# How to add a lightbox to webpage links

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Can anyone help me to show lightbox popup for links such as below,

1) [test1](http://www.google.com)
   2) [test2](http://www.yahoo.com)
   3) [test3](http://www.msn.com)

When anyone clicked below links it should show in jquery lightbox instead open in target blank or redirect on the same browser.

Comment: There is tons of different ligthbox plugins, just google 'jquery lightbox', and most of them have a good documentation and are simple to use.

Comment: Go to `fancybox plugin` http://fancybox.net/blog

Answer (score 1):

if you use fancybox plugin this will works..

```
<a id="manual1" data-image="/example-full.jpg,/example-full-2.jpg'><img src="/example-thumb.png" alt="example" /></a>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('#manual1').click(function() {
    var data = $(this).data('images').split(','),
        options = {
            padding : 38,
            nextEffect : 'fade',
            prevEffect : 'fade',
            type: 'image'
        };
    $.fancybox.open(data , options );
})
 </script>
```

Fiddle is : http://jsfiddle.net/voigtan/jJpAM/2/

Answer (score 1):

I think this will work

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
 $("a", ".rest-menuitem").click(
   function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var elementURL = $(this).attr("href");
    $.colorbox({iframe: true, href: elementURL, innerWidth: 645, innerHeight: 509});
   });
 });
</script>
```

Set **innerWidth** and **innerHeight** according to your content.